# CSS Navigation bar background vanishes on setting float property

Tags: html, css

So I have been building this css navigation bar, I have a few problems hope someone can help
. This is how it is [Navigation bar](http://jsfiddle.net/nashvail/eKgPm/) . But on setting the float property of the ".cssmenu ul li" to left the whole green background vanishes [Navigation with float enabled](http://jsfiddle.net/nashvail/y53sv/1/) . Why does this happen? Also I have used the :before pseudo class to create the underline extension effect but that doesn't seem to stretch to the whole width even I have set the width : 100% on hover. 
Thanks in advance.

since "Links to jsfiddle.net must be accompanied by code "

```
.cssmenu{
    width : auto;
    background : #27ae60;
}

.cssmenu ul{
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  line-height: 1;
  display: block;
  zoom: 1;
}

.cssmenu ul li{
  display: block;
  padding: 0;

}
```

things mess up on enabling the float property in .cssmenu ul li .

Comment: what is the ultimate goal here? To have the black line span the entire list?

Comment: No, entire li element that's hovered

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Parent elements of floated elements do not expand to their children's size. Think of this like the children were `position: absolute`.

To force the parent element to encompass all of its floated children, add `overflow: hidden` to the parent. In your case, you would add this to `.cssmenu`:

```
.cssmenu {
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/y53sv/2/)

---

As for the underlining, setting the width of the `:before` element to `100%` makes the underline the same width as the `a` element. This is the width of the text.

Instead, you should add the `:before` element to the `li` element:

```
.cssmenu ul li:before {
    ...
}

.cssmenu ul li:hover:before {
    ...
}
```

Now 100% width means the width of the `li` element, which is the "full" width of a menu item.

**Note:** You'll also have to change some metrics of the `:before` element such as `top`, `left`, etc.

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/y53sv/4/)

Comment: Thank you so much, can you help me with the other issue as well, please

Comment: You're a CSS superhero . Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Use

```
.cssmenu {
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

Demo [here](http://jsfiddle.net/y53sv/3/)

Answer (score 1):

Are you trying to inline the navigation elements?  Wondering what you're trying to accomplish, that may help us better answer your question.  I'm a little unclear, but here goes nothing!

Here's my shot:

http://jsfiddle.net/jasonbelmonti/CYR7V/

Is this what you're looking to achieve?

This is the css I used:

```
  @import url(http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:700);

.cssmenu{
    width : auto;
    background : #27ae60;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.cssmenu ul{
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  width: 100%;
  line-height: 1;
  display: block;
  zoom: 1;
}

.cssmenu ul li{
  display: inline-block;
  width: 33%;
  padding-top: 15px;
  padding-bottom: 17px;

}

.cssmenu ul li a{
    display : block;
    position : relative;
    font-family: "Open Sans";
    color : #fff;
    text-decoration: none;
    padding : 0 px;
    text-transform:  uppercase;
    transition : all .3s;
    font-size :14px;

}

.cssmenu ul li a span
{
 padding-left: 15px;
}

.cssmenu ul li a:before{
    content : ' ';
    display : block;
    height  :3px;
    width : 0px;
    background : #2c3e50;
    position : relative;
    top : 30px;
    left : -25px;
    transition : all .3s;

}

.cssmenu ul li a:hover:before{
    width : 100%;
    left: 0;
}

.cssmenu ul li a:hover{
    color : #34495e;
}
```